# Making recursive call, tail recursive

Tags: scala, recursion

I have the following recursive function

```scala
trait SequenceGenerator[T] {
  def program(l: List[T])(implicit rule: ProductionRule[T]): List[T] = {
    l.flatMap(rule.generate)
  }

  def sequenceNumber(seed: List[T], number: Int)(implicit rule: ProductionRule[T]): List[T] = {
    number match {
      case 1 => program(seed)
      case a => program(sequenceNumber(seed, a - 1))
    }
  }
}
```

I can't think of a way to make `sequenceNumber` tail recursive.

Comment: @Sam-d you should add `ProductionRule` trait to your sample to make the entire code compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind transforming methods to tailrec is to put every next calculation step into accumulator and then pass this accumulator back to the method, so that on next step you could return your accumulator or call this method again with new accumulator modified according to your step.

So you will get something like this:

```
trait SequenceGenerator[T] {

  def program(l: List[T])(implicit rule: ProductionRule[T]): List[T] = l.flatMap(rule.generate)

  def sequenceNumber(seed: List[T], number: Int)(implicit rule: ProductionRule[T]): List[T] = {

    @tailrec
    def tailRec(number: Int, acc: List[T]): List[T] =  number match {
      case 1 => acc
      case a => tailRec(a-1,program(acc))
    }

    tailRec(number,program(seed))

  }

}
```

But just FYI there is also more advanced technique for building tail recursions called `Trampoling`. It can be implemented using `scala.util.control.TailCalls` for example.

I'm not very good in this technique but it will look something like this:

```
import TailCalls._

trait SequenceGenerator[T] {

  def program(l: TailRec[List[T]])(implicit rule: ProductionRule[T]):TailRec[List[T]] = {
    l.map(_.flatMap(rule.generate))
  }

  def sequenceNumber(seed: TailRec[List[T]], number: TailRec[Int])(implicit rule: ProductionRule[T]): TailRec[List[T]] = {
    number flatMap {
      case 1 => tailcall(program(seed))
      case a => tailcall(program(sequenceNumber(seed, done(a - 1))))
    }
  }

}
```

`sequenceNumber` can't be marked as tailrec here but it actually tailrec in "background". To get real calculation result you will need to call `sequenceNumber(done(...),done(...)).result`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the posted code is an over-simplification, but it looks like you don't actually need `program()`, or recursion for that matter.

`program(seed)` is really just `seed.flatMap(rule.generate)` and so the recursion rolls out to `seed.flatMap(rule.generate).flatMap(rule.generate).flatMap(...` etc., which is what `iterate()` will do for you.

```
def sequenceNumber(seed:List[T], number:Int)(implicit rule:ProductionRule[T]):List[T] =
  Seq.iterate(seed.flatMap(rule.generate), number)(_.flatMap(rule.generate)).last
```